# What is Setup and Returns in MOQ C#?

Tags: c#, moq

I read a few tutorial on `Moq` C# package but I still can't really understand what is `Setup` and `Returns` in `Moq`.

Example,

```
mock.Setup(p => p.GetEmployeebyId(1)).ReturnsAsync("JK");
```

Example 2,

```
mock.Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<DeskBooking>())).Callback<DeskBooking>(
deskBooking =>
{
savedDeskBooking = deskBooking;
});
```

)

Comment: Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: `Setup` = When, `Returns` = What

Whenever you write unit tests then you want make sure that a given piece of functionality is working as expected. But most of the time the functionality depends on some other components / environment / external source / whatsoever.

To make your test focused and replayable we need to use test doubles. These will replace your dependencies during the test. We can categorize the test doubles like this:

- **Dummy**: simple code that returns **bogus** data
- **Fake**: a working **alternative** which can take shortcuts
- **Stub**: custom logic with **predefined** data
- **Mock**:  custom logic with **expectations** (interactive stub)
- **Shim**: custom logic **at run-time** (replace static with a delegate)
- **Spy**: **interceptors** to record calls

So, whenever you want to create a mock then you have to tell that under what circumstances how should the component behave. In other words **when** the function is called with a particular input then **what** should be the expected output.

In case of Moq you can use the `Setup` to define the when. And the `Returns` to specify the what.

Here is a simple example. Let's suppose you have the following function:

```
private IService service;
string MyMethod()
{
   int number = service.GetNextNumber();
   if(number % 2 == 0)
   {
       return "even";
   }
   else
   {
       return "odd";
   }
}
```

Then you can write the following to test cases:

```
public void GivenAnEvenNumber_WhenICallMyMethod_ThenItShouldReturnEven
{
   //Arrange
   var serviceMock = new Mock<IService>();
   serviceMock
      .Setup(svc => svc.GetNextNumber())
      .Returns(2);
   ...

   //Act
   var result = SUT.MyMethod();

   //Assert
   Assert.Equal("even", result);
}

public void GivenAnOddNumber_WhenICallMyMethod_ThenItShouldReturnOdd
{
   //Arrange
   var serviceMock = new Mock<IService>();
   serviceMock
      .Setup(svc => svc.GetNextNumber())
      .Returns(1);
   ...

   //Act
   var result = SUT.MyMethod();

   //Assert
   Assert.Equal("odd", result);
}
```

So, as you can see we have used `Setup` and `Returns` to direct the control flow in each test case.

---

Your second example can be considered a **Spy**, because there you are recording the input for latter assessment.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explaination, peter.

Comment: @Steve Do you need any further clarification regarding this topic?

Answer (score 3):

In example 1

```
mock.Setup(p => p.GetEmployeebyId(1)).ReturnsAsync("JK");
```

sets up your mock so when `GetEmployeebyId` is called with a 1 as the parameter, the mock will return "JK".

In example 2

```
mock.Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<DeskBooking>())).Callback<DeskBooking>(
deskBooking =>
{
savedDeskBooking = deskBooking;
});
```

when the `Save` method is called with any parameter of type `DeskBooking`, the lambda function will save the parameter in the `savedDeskBooking` variable. You can then test that you've saved the `DeskBooking` you expected.

Comment: If example 2 is using the same method name as in example 1, how will it looks it?